# How to completely disable all Internet Explorer Script Error dialogs

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, selenium

Can someone please tell me how to disable Internet Explorer Script Error - says:

> An Error has occurred in the script on this page

```
   ...
   Error: Unspecified error
   ...
```

Please don't Say to Go to `Tools -> I.Options -> Advanced` ...turning off debugging etc etc..

I have tried all that and this popup dialog still comes up.

Some forums suggested turning off a service called: Machine Debug Manager (MDM), the problem is that I can't find this service running on my windows version. Why?

```
System
   Windows XP
   Professional
   Version 2002 
   Service Pack 3
```

There's gotta be some way to completely turn off this dialog so that it doesn't come up. I don't mind deleting the entire registry to make this stop. that's how frustrated I am with it. FYI, I get this while running automated test using selenium RC on IE6. Hope this enough info. Thanks so much

Comment: When you say things like "Etc Etc" you leave it to everyone else to try to guess what exactly you did.  Since the Advanced dialog contains 3 different options which control script error dialogs, and you only mention one of them, what are we to conclude?

Comment: Added some clarifications on the instructions, as requested (see comments of my answer)

Answer (score 7):

regarding `MDM.exe`:

From: 
[What To Do When . . . Your Browser Displays Script Error Warnings](http://www.smartcomputing.com/editorial/article.asp?article=articles%2F2006%2Fs1711%2F35s11%2F35s11.asp)

> Some, but not all, Windows users have the **`Mdm.exe`** file on their system.
>   This is the Machine Debug Manager, a program installed with the Microsoft Script Editor to provide support for program debugging. Users of Microsoft Office 2000 and above will have this program on their system. It also can be downloaded from the Windows Update Web site (update.microsoft.com).
>
> Because the `Mdm.exe` file can be a source of script error warnings, you can disable it to prevent seeing more unnecessary messages.
>   You can use the Search tool (click Start and Search) to find the Mdm.exe file.
>   However, a quicker method to disable this program is to open the **Run dialog box (click Start and Run), type msconfig, and click OK**.
>   This opens the System Configuration Utility dialog box.
>
> **On the Startup tab, look for the `Mdm.exe` file on the list.
>
>   If it’s listed, deselect the corresponding checkbox. You will then need to restart your computer.**
>   Don’t worry if the file isn’t listed on the Startup tab. Even if the Search tool found **`Mdm.exe`** on your system, you may never need to run this program.

---

Note: in the same article, it is also mentioned:

> When turned on, Internet Explorer’s pop-up blocker tool can be a source of script error warnings.

[image]

Comment: Hello Von, thanks for your detailed instructions. I have found mdm.exe through the explorer search but dont know what to do with it. Its not clear from your solution what you want me to do with this file. Could you please clarify a little. Thanks again

Comment: You need to run "msconfig" and look for mdm.exe in the "Startup" tab in order to deselect it (it will no longer executed at startup). Basically, you just need to follow the instructions in bold.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for a solution for later versions of IE (I cannot verify if this works on IE6) and if the above solution is not working for you, try this:

Assuming you're running from the command line, run with `-multiWindow`. I had previously been running with `-singlewindow` which was throwing the Script Errors.

This worked for me on IE9. I have not checked IE8 yet, though.

Hope this helps :D